# PHP CodeIgniter Error Log Not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, configuration, error-handling

I've following settings in php.ini-

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT|E_WARNING
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = "/var/log/php_errors.log"
```

And config.php in CodeIgniter-

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
$config['log_path'] = getcwd() . '/' . SYSDIR . '/logs/';
```

In the Index.php file-

```
case 'development':
error_reporting(E_ALL);
break;

case 'testing':
case 'production':
     error_reporting(0);
```

When it's "development" in Index.php, i see warnings, and error messages also on webpage, PHP Fatal error, PHP Parse error in php_errors.log file. But if I make it "Production", no error/warnings are not displayed nor logged in the file. How do I log all errors and messages without displaying?

(Just to mention here- The folder application/logs/ is 777 and there all I have is index.html that has "403 Forbidden" written in it. )

Comment: Is there some over writing of configurations happening?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the log_path as the default ''?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But nothing is happening. I even tried full log path- 'home/theuser/path/to/log/' It's just not working... Do you have any idea of what might be reason?

Comment: Have you looked at your error.log to see if it throws any errors?

Answer (score 8):

Please check your config/config.php file and check your settings

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

**Note :**  

0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
2 = Debug Messages
3 = Informational Messages
4 = All Messages
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I think you are mixing two things together.

**error_reporting** in php settings shows you errors created during php script execution.
If you use "desplay_errors" = Off. PHP won't show any of those errors. You have turned on log_errors and setup a folder. So PHP error will get to the /var/log/php_errors.log file.

On the other hand CodeIgniter uses function:

```
log_message('level,'message')
```

which serves for storing errors/debug/info into log files. If you call

```
log_message('error','I'm an error!')
```

somewhere in your code, you really should have a new log file in log directory.

Internaly CodeIgniter uses log_message() if there are any PHP errors. I'm really not sure how it will behave while display_error is set to Off (he will think that there was no error?).

Try calling your own **log_message** and turn **display_errors** to **On**. I think that it should help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set error_reporting(E_ALL); under case 'production' in your index.php file